# Php code to display latest data on top always and push previous values bottom

Tags: php

[Problem statement resembles this picture]

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Invsv.png

present output: 
1
2
3
4
Expected output:
4
3
2
1
I dont want array_reverse.

Comment: code I have trierd:
$result="select x1,y1,angle1 from csv_data  ORDER BY x1   ";
//query on database
$output=mysqli_query($con,$result);
//no.of rows
$rowcount=mysqli_num_rows($output);
//fetching all data
$row=mysqli_fetch_all($output,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
//iterating each row
for($i=0;$i<=$rowcount;$i++)
{
    echo $row[$i]['x1']."\t".$row[$i]['y1']."\t".$row[$i]['angle1']."<br>";
    ob_flush();
    flush();
    sleep($delay);
}

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! add image into your question instead of link and also remove code from comments and add these code into your question with well formatted

Answer (score 0):

Is there any reason you don't want to use array_reverse()?

You can alternatively use `krsort($arr);`
That will sort by keys descending.

Comment: array_reverse gives same result as order by desc. i want to push down the first Inn values to bottom